# Confusion in peak detector circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor, diodes

When we apply a sinusoidal voltage source as input to a peak detector circuit (assuming capacitor is initially discharge and ideal diode and ideal voltage source), the diode becomes in forward biased for first positive peak and charging of capicitor takes place until peak of the source voltage. But after that diode becomes reverse biased because capacitor voltage becomes higher than source voltage but I cannot understand how and why  capacitor voltage does not follow ideal voltage source all the time?

What's wrong in this theory as follows? A capacitor is connected parllel to an ideal voltage source when diode is in forward bias so capacitor voltage must follow ideal voltage source at all times to satisfy KVL condition?

Comment: In order for the capacitor voltage to go down, charge has to be removed from it. The diode prevents this.

Comment: Because there's a diode in the way.

Comment: Think of the diode as trying to be a one-way valve or ratchet - the voltage can get lifted up, but not dragged down again (of course in the real world, there will be leakage...)

Comment: @Aaron ,so diode not only depends on polarity of voltage across it but also current through it?

Comment: A diode only allows current to flow from Anode to Cathode. Current always flows from higher potential to lower potential.

Comment: @Chris Stratton thanks for comment,but analogies does not work well all the time ,if you have time could you explain it in more detail what actually going on in circuit ?

Comment: @user215805: An "ideal" diode has either 0 volt drop and forward current, or reverse voltage and zero current.  The most common simple model is not too different... between 0 and 0.7V drop and forward current, or reverse voltage and zero current.  If you are more familiar with fluid flow, consider a diode to be the electronic version of a **check valve**.

Comment: Draw a simple schematic of the circuit for a diode detector. Then explain what you think is happening as the sinusoidal voltage source goes through a single cycle from 0V to it's peak. What happens as the voltage drops back to zero, goes negative and returns to 0V.